# cast datetime[ms] to datetime[ns] in polars

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

I'd like to cast a column with the type datetype[ms] to datetime[ns] in polars. Is there a easy way to do this? I think there's a problem with group_by_dynamic when using datetime[ms] and I'd like to test this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
s = pl.date_range(
        datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2),
        interval="3h", time_unit="ns"
)

# divide by 1 million is from ns to ms
(s.cast(int) // 1_000_000).cast(pl.Datetime).dt.cast_time_unit("ms")
```

```
shape: (9,)
Series: '' [datetime[ms]]
[
    2021-01-01 00:00:00
    2021-01-01 03:00:00
    2021-01-01 06:00:00
    2021-01-01 09:00:00
    2021-01-01 12:00:00
    2021-01-01 15:00:00
    2021-01-01 18:00:00
    2021-01-01 21:00:00
    2021-01-02 00:00:00
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`cast_time_unit`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.cast_time_unit.html) directly. It works more generally to convert `datetime[x]` to `datetime[y]` without you requiring to think about conversion factors.
For example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(data = {
    date : pl.date_range(
        datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2),
        interval="3h", time_unit="ns", eager=True,
    )}
)

df = df.with_columns(pl.col("date").dt.cast_time_unit("ms"))
```

Also produces the desired result

```
>>> print(df)
shape: (9, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ dates               │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[ms]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-01 03:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-01 06:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-01 09:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-01 12:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-01 15:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-01 18:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-01 21:00:00 │
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```